# RecycleView auto-refresh problem (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hello again guys you have been helpful in the last week with my journey to learn kotlin and my first time kotlin app.
i am making an shopping list app so i use recycleView to present the use shopping list inside each shoppingList item the user have 2 button (plus and minus) that allow him to choose how many of this item he would like to purchase.
for now i set up only the plus button but each time i update my database on the new Amount of the item it doesnt use my "refreshlist" function and i cant find a way to call this function after finish my "adding"
function
FYI: the whole shopping_list is inside fragment.
this is the shopping_list.kt file

```
package com.example.pricetag.fragments

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.pricetag.R
import com.example.pricetag.fragments.DTO.ItemList
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_shopping_list.*


lateinit var dbHandler: DBHandler

class shopping_list() : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        
    
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false)
        dbHandler = DBHandler(view.context)

        val addItem_button = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab_shoppiglist)


        addItem_button.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            val tempView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shoppinglist,null)
            val text_result = tempView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_Itemlist)
            dialog.setView(tempView)
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Add") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                if (text_result.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val itemList = ItemList()
                    itemList.name = text_result.text.toString()
                    dbHandler.addItem(itemList)
                    refreshList()
                }


            }
            dialog.setNeutralButton("DeleteList") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                    dbHandler.delete()
                    refreshList()
            }
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int->

            }
            dialog.show()
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        rv_shoppinglist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        val verticalDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(
            rv_shoppinglist.getContext(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
        )
        val verticalDivider =
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity!!, R.drawable.rv_divider)
        verticalDecoration.setDrawable(verticalDivider!!)
        rv_shoppinglist.addItemDecoration(verticalDecoration)

    }


    override fun onResume() {
        refreshList()
        super.onResume()
    }

    private fun refreshList(){
        rv_shoppinglist.adapter = ShoppinglistAdpter(this.requireContext(), dbHandler, dbHandler.getItem())
    }


    class ShoppinglistAdpter(val context: Context, dbHandler: DBHandler,  val list: MutableList<ItemList>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppinglistAdpter.ViewHolder>(){

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, pl: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_shoppinglist,p0,false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            holder.itemName.text = list[p1].name
            holder.itemAmount.text = list[p1].amount.toString()
            holder.addButton.setOnClickListener{
                dbHandler.changeAmount(list[p1].id.toInt())
            }

        }

        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val itemName : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
            val itemAmount : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_amount)
            val addButton : ImageButton = v.findViewById(R.id.IB_add)

        }

    }

}
```

let me know if u need another piece of code so i will add to this post for your ability to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found a solution ill post it hope it will help someone in the feature
it was simple as that ive tried it before but instead of using "This" i used "shoppinglist()" which i guess intended to be new object of shoppingList

so what ive done is adding inside of ShoppinglistAdapter args list "val shoppingList: shopping_list and then called refreshlist method where i needed it

```
    class ShoppinglistAdpter(val context: Context, val shoppingList: shopping_list, dbHandler: DBHandler, val list: MutableList<ItemList>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppinglistAdpter.ViewHolder>(){

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, pl: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(shoppingList.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_shoppinglist,p0,false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            holder.itemName.text = list[p1].name
            holder.itemAmount.text = list[p1].amount.toString()
            holder.addButton.setOnClickListener{
                dbHandler.changeAmount(list[p1].id.toInt())
                shoppingList.refreshList()
            }

        }

        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val itemName : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
            val itemAmount : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_amount)
            val addButton : ImageButton = v.findViewById(R.id.IB_add)

        }

    }
```

Comment: I've seen that you added the refreshList function inside of your onClickListener. But for your next project, try using the groupie library. It makes using recyclerview's much easier and fun

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Kotlin but I suggest you try this:

#### 1. Add adapter as lateinit variable

```kotlin
lateinit var dbHandler: DBHandler
lateinit var adapter: ShoppinglistAdpter

class shopping_list() : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        
    
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false)
        dbHandler = DBHandler(view.context)
        adapter = ShoppinglistAdpter(this.requireContext(), dbHandler, dbHandler.getItem() as ArrayList<ItemList>)

        rv_shoppinglist.adapter = adapter
```

#### 2. Add a variable list in RecyclerView.Adapter as shown below.

```kotlin
class ShoppinglistAdpter(val context: Context, dbHandler: DBHandler): RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppinglistAdpter.ViewHolder>(){

    var list: ArrayList<ItemList> = ArrayList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            Log.d("List changed and value size is ${value.size}")
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, pl: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_shoppinglist,p0,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        holder.itemName.text = list[p1].name
        holder.itemAmount.text = list[p1].amount.toString()
        holder.addButton.setOnClickListener{
            dbHandler.changeAmount(list[p1].id.toInt())
        }

    }
}
```

Then instead of reassigning adapter regularly, call this:

```kotlin
private fun refreshList(){
    adapter.list = dbHandler.getItem() as ArrayList<ItemList>
// adapter.list will call notifyDataSetChanged - this, I think, was the problem you were facing
}
```

Comment: tried it and got this ERR
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pricetag/com.example.pricetag.DashbordActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: rv_shoppinglist must not be null

Comment: Have you tried using viewbinding in your fragment? Maybe it will prevent the above error.